does extension to reals of an arbitrary signal with a zero tail eventually cross a threshold
Suppose I have a sampled signal $S(x) :=\space [ \space ..., X_{-2}, \space X_{-1}, \space 0, \space 0, \space 0, \space 0, \space ... \space ]$
where $\{X\}_{n}$ is bounded by $\pm1$ when n is a negative integer, and 0 at all other integers. The real extension for $S(x)$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a sum of all sinc functions scaled such that it is $X_{n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and 0 at all other integer points. Suppose that each $X_{N}$ is additionally constrained so that it is a multiple of some epsilon, such as $\varepsilon = 2^{-k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
for every $S$, does there exist a time $t$ such that for all $u \in \mathbb{R}, u >= t$, we have $|S(u)| < \varepsilon$?

I think I'm missing something here. If $X_N$ is not decaying, the function will not decay. The extra constraint of $X_N = m  \cdot 2^{-k}$ doesn't help here at all. To me that constraint just sounds like "$X_n$ is quantized", but that will have very little or no impact on the convergence behavior. As long as the only real constraint is $|X_N| \leq 1$ the function will continue roughly at the same level forever.

$X_t$ is zero for $t \in \mathbb{Z} >= 0$ @Hilmar


does there exist a time $t$ such that for all $u \in \mathbb{R}, u >= t$, we have $|S(u)| < \varepsilon$?$

Not as I interpret the question.
For simplicity we can just flip the signal in time and shift by one sample and can write the function as
$$s(u) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A[n] \cdot \text{sinc}(u-nT) \tag{1}$$
where $A[n] = X_{-n-1}$ from the original question. $T = 1$ is the sample rate and the discrete signal would be
$$s[n] = s(nT) = A[n] \tag{2}$$
$A[n]$ is bounded by $|A[n]| \leq 1 \tag{3}$
The maximum possible amplitude of that signal occurs when all sincs have maximum amplitude and add up with the same sign. The sincs change sign at every whole number, except $u = 0$. In other words each sinc has a constant sign on every interval that's bounded by two consecutive whole numbers. To maximize the function in that interval, we just have to pick the sign for each sinc so that they all add up. Turns out each sequence
$$ A[n] = [...-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1...] \tag{4}$$
will do this and maximize the interval between the two consecutive 1s.
To be precise, we can maximize the function on any interval  $[M, M+1], M \in \mathbb{I}$ for the sequence
$$A_M[n] = \begin{cases} -1^{n-M} & n \leq M \\
-1^{n-(M+1)} & n > M \end{cases} \tag{4a}$$
The maximum will occur at $u = M+0.5$ and is
$$s_{max,M} = \sum_{n=0}^{n=+\infty}|\text{sinc}(n+0.5=M)| =
\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{n=+\infty} \frac{1}{n+0.5-M} \rightarrow \infty
 \tag{5}$$
which diverges for all $M$. I.e. the function as written is not bounded at all. The "trigger sequence" can occur anywhere in the signal, so there is no upper limit as a function of time.

Suppose that each $X_{N}$ is additionally constrained so that it is a multiple of some epsilon, such as $\varepsilon = 2^{-k}, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

This is just saying that $X_N$ is quantized. This really has no impact on the entire consideration as long as the values $X_N = 1$ and $X_N = -1$ are allowed.

I'm confused about eq. 4 -> why is it nonzero in both ends off to infinity?

or is there an implied 0, at the LHS in the ellipsis?

I may be wrong, but it looks like you are analyzing the wrong side of the signal?

when I plot your example, it does indeed have a min/maximum at N+0.5, but it looks like the minimum and maximum is closer to zero the further we go on (but it may in fact never converge to 0)

well, ignore my previous remark, it seems to be a limitation of the way I'm plotting, but if I understand this correctly, we have a nyquist sine wave on the left of zero with magnitude 1, and a nyquist frequency infinite wave on the right (0 inf 0 -inf)?

actually, it looks like the generated wave actually is infinity nearly everywhere

@micsthepick: Re equation (4): I'm a bit sloppy with the one-sided ness of the signal. The left side should indeed continue until $n=0$. It's tedious to write it correctly and the conclusion is the same either way. The signal can be unbounded regardless of whether its one or two sided.
